# SQL - Query to find if a string contains part of the value in Column

Tags: mysql, sql, string, contains

I am trying to write a Query to find if a string contains part of the value in Column (Not to confuse with the query to find if a column contains part of a string).

Say for example I have a column in a table with values

> ABC,XYZ

If I give search string

> ABCDEFG

then I want the row with **ABC** to be displayed.

If my search string is **XYZDSDS** then the row with value **XYZ** should be displayed

Comment: Please clarify your question and fully describe how it should work with more examples. There are too many unknowns at present. Does your column always contain 3 characters? Can you match anywhere in the match string (not just at the start)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The answer would be "use LIKE".

See the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

You can do `WHERE 'string' LIKE CONCAT(column , '%')`

Thus the query becomes:

```
select * from t1 where 'ABCDEFG' LIKE CONCAT(column1,'%');
```

If you need to match anywhere in the string:

```
select * from t1 where 'ABCDEFG' LIKE CONCAT('%',column1,'%');
```

Here you can see it working in a fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1596/4

Comment: How is the performance impact if the column1 is indexed? Is it going to be slower?

Comment: `CONCAT` is the key ingredient here. If you try `'%' + column1 + '%'` it won't work

Answer (score 4):

```
Select * from table where @param like '%' + col + '%'
```

Comment: Thanks. It helps. Just a small modification. Select * from table where @param like '%' || col || '%'

Comment: This didn't work for me. The correct answer is Turophile's

Comment: This didn't work for me also. When the answer needs modification why have you makred it as accepted answer @user2354254.

Answer (score 3):

First, you appear to be storing lists of things in a column.  This is the wrong approach to storing values in the database.  You should have a junction table, with one row per entity and value -- that is, a separate row for `ABC` and `XYZ` in your example.  SQL has a great data structure for storing lists.  It is called a "table", not a "string".

If you are stuck with such a format and using MySQL, there is a function that can help:

```
where find_in_set('ABC', col)
```

MySQL treats a comma delimited string as a "set" and offers this function.  However, this function cannot use indexes, so it is not particularly efficient.  Did I mention that you should use a junction table instead?