# Peewee orm revert contains/startswith/endswith

Tags: python, python-3.x, peewee

I have this and it works perfect

```
Model.name.startswith(name)
```

but i need this

```
name.startswith(Model.name)
```

Occurrence of a field value in a string.
Thx

Comment: `Model.name` has no value: it described a field in your model. If you have a *specific instance* (that you got e.g. from a previous query) it makes sense to ask about the name.

Comment: i need something like this, but with peewee https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29389293/sql-query-to-find-if-a-string-contains-part-of-the-value-in-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Value(). Note that a wildcard is added

```
Model.select().where(Value(name).startswith(Model.name))
```

The corresponding SQL, approximately:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM model_tbl
WHERE '<value in name var>' LIKE (name || '%')
```

Comment: thx it's great, but Value exist only from peewee 3 version? there is no alternative for the second version?