# SQL - Query to find records that contain part of the value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have table `zipcode` which has a column called `code`. The `Code` column contains the prefix of zipcodes like

```
395
453
302
1203
12
```

I want to write an SQL query that checks if the provided `zipcode` matches one of the values in the table. (Something like isValid)

I want to avoid writing all zip codes in the database.

Valid Input zipcode

```
395004
395152
3952
1256
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: *I want to write sql query from* and why you do not do it? Where do you stuck

Comment: provide more detail about your question. It's vague.

Comment: @Jens i don't know how to write sql queries for this type of situation.

Comment: are only these 4 code valid?

Comment: No there is lots of other too. Code that start with 395
453
302
1203
12 is valid

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Do you want to write a raw SQL query, or one based on Laravels models?

Comment: @NicoHaase Just query only but i found solution Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple sql query:

```
select * 
from zipcode 
where '395004' LIKE CONCAT(code,'%');
```

references: [SQL - Query to find if a string contains part of the value in Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29389293/sql-query-to-find-if-a-string-contains-part-of-the-value-in-column)

Comment: Thanks it worked, Just write answer in perfect format.

Comment: As an alternative you can write the condition like: `where '%' + code LIKE '395004'`

Comment: @SamySammour no, it's not worked.

Comment: @Protap Singh, can you write this in laravel format?

Comment: @PramodTapaniya In laravel you have to use DB::Raw for concat.

Comment: @PramodTapaniya what is the database engine?

Comment: @SamySammour MySQL

Comment: Ok, it won't work! It is a valid SQL Server statement